# Unable to setup PyCharm Geo Viewer, enable JCEF setting unavailable

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pycharm

Has anyone used the geo viewer in PyCharm? I was looking for an equivalent to the VS Code geo data viewer extension and found this [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/tables-view-data.html#using-geo-viewer-for-spatial-data). However, when following the steps I cannot find the settings for JCEF anywhere, and clicking the search for geo viewer doesn't open anything.

I'm on the latest Windows version of PyCharm Pro and have PostgreSQL setup and installed. Looking for any guidance as to possible required dependencies I'm missing or how to set up use of geo viewer.